# Comparing centers of group and a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let G be a non-abelian group with nilpotent subgroup H of index p such that Z(G) is contained in H. Is there anything we can say about Z(H) / Z(G)?

(I am an undergrad doing research in group theory and have taught myself these properties/concepts on a need-to-know basis, so I have no idea if there are any theorems that can help here)

Comment: Is $p$ prime???

Comment: Yes - my mistake, thought I put that.

Comment: I don't think you can say much. $H$ could be abelian, so $Z(H) = H$, but $Z(G)$ could be trivial or very small. Consider dihedral group for example.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully some other properties will help me.